# Enable Verbose Logging for Java (rt.jar)

Tags: java, logging, jboss, log4j

I am new to stack overflow, please pardon if I make any mistake on my first post.

I am trying to enable VERBOSE logging for all classes under java package: sun.rmi.*
the container being used is JBOSS-4.2.2 and there is a jboss-log4.xml  in our application.

I have used the following JAVA_OPTS during start-up hoping to see the verbose logging within TCPChannel.java which is part of rt.jar(http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/rmi/transport/tcp/TCPChannel.java.html) but it did not work.

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS  -Djava.rmi.server.logCalls=true 
-Dsun.rmi.server.logLevel=VERBOSE 
-Dsun.rmi.client.logCalls=true 
-Dsun.rmi.transport.tcp.logLevel=VERBOSE 
-Dsun.rmi.transport.logLevel=VERBOSE"
```

Below is jboss-log4j.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" 
 debug="false">

<!-- A time/date based rolling appender -->
<appender name="FILE" 
   class="org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender">
<errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
<param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/trace.log"/>
<param name="Append" value="true"/>
<param name="Threshold" value="TRACE#org.jboss.logging.XLevel"/>
<!-- Rollover at midnight each day -->
<param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%X{jobName} 
  %X{token}] [%c] - %m%n"/>
</layout>
</appender>

<!-- Limit the org.apache category to INFO as its DEBUG is verbose -->
<category name="org.apache">
<priority value="INFO"/>
</category>

<!-- Limit the jacorb category to WARN as its INFO is verbose -->
<category name="jacorb">
<priority value="WARN"/>
</category>

<!-- Limit the org.jgroups category to WARN as its INFO is verbose -->
<category name="org.jgroups">
 <priority value="DEBUG"/>
</category>

<!-- Limit the org.quartz category to INFO as its DEBUG is verbose -->
<category name="org.quartz">
  <priority value="INFO"/>
</category>

<!-- Limit the JSR77 categories -->
<category name="org.jboss.management">
  <priority value="DEBUG"/>
</category>

<category name="org.jboss.serial">
  <priority value="TRACE"/>
</category>

<category name="org.jboss.remoting">
  <priority value="TRACE" class="org.jboss.logging.XLevel"></priority>
</category>

<category name="org.jboss">
  <priority value="TRACE" class="org.jboss.logging.XLevel"></priority>
</category>  

<category name="org.jnp">
  <priority value="TRACE"/>
</category>

 <root>
 <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
 <!--appender-ref ref="SYSLOG"/-->
</root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

How do I enable logging using system property in jboss-log4j.xml if I believe the log4j.xml is overriding my java_opts
I am using this link as reference: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/logging.html

I want to try the category "client-side" "server-side" described in the above link, but I am clear on the syntax, if any example syntax can be provided, it would be helpful.

Any help in getting Verbose logging turned on is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `sun.rmi.*` are Java SE classes, it is highly unlikely that they will use log4j logging.  Therefore, trying to configure logging for those classes via the log4j configs is (IMO) doomed to fail.

Instead, you should read about how to enable RMI logging [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/logging.html)) using the standard [`java.util.logging` framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/logging/index.html), and configuring the logging via a `java.util.logging` properties file; see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html#a1.8).

I think that log4j and java.util.logging can co-exist, provided that you don't try to log into the same log files.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Stephen. I was able to enable logging on Java SE classes via the API by tweaking logging.properties file under jre/lib/